# Не переведён текст описания меты для незалогиненного пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, нет-в-transifex, новые-участники

При открытии https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/ в незалогиненном виде отображается:

> Welcome!
>
> This site is for **discussion** about [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). You must have an account there to participate.
>
> [справка »](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help?mnu=1)

Надо бы перевести.

Comment: Или к тексту на английском добавить перевод?

Comment: @avp, не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy: avp имеет в виду, что можно оставить текст на двух языках, чтобы и англоязычные посетители не растерялись.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а зачем нерусскоязычным пользователям забредать на эту мету? В любом случае, вряд ли так просто добавить лишний блок?

Comment: @Qwertiy: скорее всего это почти нереализуемо. Придется перепиливать шаблон, который один на всех. Португальцы не парятся, у них один вариант на португальском. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Qwertiy, NickVolynkin правильно догадался. Да, мне кажется 2 языка было бы нормально для случайно забредших и не понимающих русского.

Answer (score 1):

> Добро пожаловать!
>
> Этот сайт — для **обсуждения** Stack Overflow на русском. Чтобы принять участие, вам необходимо зарегистрироваться.

В transifex строки не нашёл.

Comment: "Зарегистрироваться" ли? Ведь для меты ещё и лимит репутации есть, так что просто регистрации недостаточно. В оригинале "must have an account", а не "must sign up". К тому же, это в любом случае как-то не очень по отношению к зарегистрированным пользователям.

Comment: @Qwertiy: разве это не одно и то же? К тому же, без репутации можно например комментарий плюсануть. Тоже участие. )

Comment: Вообще-то нельзя...

Comment: @Qwertiy: без регистрации нельзя, а с низкой репутацией вроде бы можно.